# When calling an array only the first element is used?

Tags: python, arrays, call

When calling `QuarterlySales` into the `DetermineRate` procedure it only uses the first number in the array every time the loop goes around. I think I have it indexed properly. Also it only prints out 9 numbers when it should print out 10.

```
def FillQuarterlySales(QuarterlySales):
    #declare local variables
    Index = 0
    QuarterlySales = [0] * 10
    #Loading the array
    QuarterlySales = [21487, 22450, 7814, 12458, 4325, 9247, 18125, 5878, 16875, 10985]
    #Determine the quarterly sales based on the index
    return QuarterlySales

def DetermineRate(QuarterlySales):
    #declare local variables
    Rate = float()
    Index = 0
    Counter = 0
    Rates = [Index] * 9
    for Index in range (9):
        if QuarterlySales[Counter] < 5000:
            Rate = 0
        elif QuarterlySales[Counter] < 10000:
            Rate = 0.04
        elif QuarterlySales[Counter] < 15000:
            Rate = 0.08
        elif QuarterlySales[Counter] < 20000:
            Rate = 0.12
        else:
            Rate = 0.15
        #end if
        Rates[Index] = Rate
    #end for
    return Rates
```

There is no error code but when I print out rates to make sure they are correct the array is filled with the same number. This is happening anywhere I call `QuarterlySales` throughout the program as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use `Counter` to index `QuarterlySales` instead of `Index`.

But your question shows some inexperience with python, so let's try to address some other issues, too.

```
Rates = [Index] * 9
...
QuarterlySales = [0] * 10
```

This looks like you're trying to do allocation in advance, which is almost always unnecessary in python.  Certainly for lists of only ten elements, it hurts more than it helps.

Instead do this:

```
Rates = []
...
QuarterlySales = []
```

and then just use the `.append()` method to add sequential data elements to the list.

For example:

```
def DetermineRate(QuarterlySales):
    Rates = []
    for sales in QuarterlySales:
        if sales < 5000:
            Rates.append(0.)
        elif sales < 10000:
            Rates.append(0.04)
        elif sales < 15000:
            Rates.append(0.08)
        elif sales < 20000:
            Rates.append(0.12)
        else:
            Rates.append(0.15)
    return Rates
```

Comment: the reason I  have QuarterlySales = [0] * 10 is because that is how my teacher wants it, this is part of a final exam for my first programming class, if thats how she wants it thats how its got to be. but i do understand what you mean and I can use that in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Tell your teacher that SO told her we'd like her to solicit advice on the assignments she uses here on SO.  :)

Comment: she would actually have to be online for that, for teaching an online class she sure isn't online very often haha